# codename one audio play back crash on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, media, codenameone, playback

I've noticed I'm getting crashes on iOS when playing back audio. Seems to be when calling the .cleanup() method on a Media object.

I removed the calls to cleanup, but it still crashes, just takes a little longer, I'm assuming it's when the GC is run.

the code is kinda spread out but looks something like:

```
media = MediaManager.createMedia({path to media}, false);
media.play();
...
media.cleanup();
```

When it crashes there is no stack trace, but the console output looks like this:

`<Error>: {app name}(805,0x381b5000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1a122640: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:{app package}[0x5cf8][805]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 mediaserverd[43] <Notice>: '' {app package}(pid = 805) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:{app package}[0x5cf8]' crashed.
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 2041398975621: id={app package} pid=805, state=0
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 ReportCrash[809] <Error>: assertion failed: 13E238: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15927 [2171E90D-32AA-3F60-9692-C2F8E0D4B1A0]: 0x0
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 Unknown[809] <Error>: 
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 ReportCrash[809] <Warning>: os_activity_diagnostic_for_pid() failed!
Apr 28 08:53:12 iPod-4 ReportCrash[809] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[805] {app name}
Apr 28 08:53:13 iPod-4 ReportCrash[809] <Warning>: Saved type '109(109_Handover)' report (1 of max 25) at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/{app name}-2016-04-28-085313.ips`

Seems like it's either when exiting the form that controls the media object or when trying to play the sound again (by creating a new media object on the same path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see an issue I filed it here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1750